# How to Update QLabel from PyQt to new string each second?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

So i'm trying to code a running text in python, but i stuck in figuring how to update my string in Qlabel each second so it looks like a running text. Here is my code

```
label = QLabel('Hello World  ')
label.move(70, 40)
label.setParent(form)
```

Until now i only know how to put the last character of the string to the first, and it's something like this :

```
old = label.text()
new = old[len(old)-1:]+old[0:len(old)-1]
label.settext(new)
```

What i need to know is how to repeat my code above over and over again EACH SECOND so the text look like it's running.

Please kindly help teach me how to do it, thanks for your appreciation and for your time. And sorry for my bad English.

Click here to see all the code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a `QTimer`.

```
def onTimeout():
    old = label.text()
    new = old[len(old)-1:]+old[0:len(old)-1]
    label.setText(new)
label = QLabel("Hello World  ")
timer = QTimer()
timer.timeout.connect(onTimeout)
timer.start(1000)
```

*Note: change `label.settext()` to `label.setText()`*

Comment: I try to code the following 
'timer.timeout.connect(ontimeout())'

but it give me error